# Resize column width in JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using a `JFileChooser` which allows me to browse to an Excel file.

The file chooser appears fine when it opens initially, but as soon as I start browsing to a different location, the column width for Name reduces a lot.

How can I stop this from happening and keep the same column width whilst browsing to different locations?

Initial display of `JFileChooser`

[image]

After browsing to a different location

[image]

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));

fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(selectedDir);
Action details = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("viewTypeDetails");
```

Comment: Tags & watchers: [tag:java] 1.3M, [tag:swing] 7.4K, [tag:jfilechooser] 9. 
By using up to 5 relevant tags, questions can get far more attention. ;)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) 3) `fileChooser.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 0):

The following code was tested with Java 11.
It uses slightly modified methods from sun.swing.FilePane.

```
public class FileChooserFix extends JFileChooser {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable            detailsTable;

    public FileChooserFix() {
        super();
        Action details = getActionMap().get("viewTypeDetails");
        details.actionPerformed(null);
        detailsTable = findChildComponent(this, JTable.class);
    }

    private <T> T findChildComponent(Container container, Class<T> cls) {
        int n = container.getComponentCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Component comp = container.getComponent(i);
            if (cls.isInstance(comp)) {
                return cls.cast(comp);
            }
            else if (comp instanceof Container) {
                T c = findChildComponent((Container) comp, cls);
                if (c != null) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentDirectory(File dir) {
        super.setCurrentDirectory(dir);
        fixNameColumnWidth();
    }

    private void fixNameColumnWidth() {
        if (detailsTable != null) {
            JViewport viewport = (JViewport) detailsTable.getParent();
            int viewWidth = viewport.getSize().width;
            TableColumn nameCol = detailsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
            int tableWidth = detailsTable.getPreferredSize().width;
            if (tableWidth < viewWidth) {
                nameCol.setPreferredWidth(nameCol.getPreferredWidth() + 
                                    viewWidth - tableWidth);
            }
        }
    }
}
```